# 7zip, Extract to a folder as default in the GUI

Tags: gui, 7-zip

I am using 7zip for the first time coming over from WinRAR but its missing an important feature for me.

I want to be able to extract my files to a folder like so:

C:/Downloads/file.zip
press extract button
C:/Downloads/file/contents

I am aware that it is possible to direct the extract by browsing folder structure but I wondered if there was a way to set it up automatically?

I am regularly seeing the cmd version mentioned but I dont want to have to use the cmd line if i dont have to... its much easier to use the GUI if you ask me!

Thx in advanced!

Comment: If 7-zip is installed and you enabled the Explorer context menu extensions, you can just right-click a zip file, head to the 7-zip submenu and say "Extract to <folder named after file>".  I don't believe there's a way to tell it to do that via the actual 7-zip GUI.

Answer (score 3):

Context menu works (see response from Julian Knight), however, I figured out another way to make it work if you have the 7zip gui already opened. (it's more natural for my brain to just double click the file instead of right clicking to get the context menu)

1. Press the "go to upper folder" icon. (7zip will go up and select the archive file)
2. press extract (it'll prefill the create new folder text box, same screen as the context menu)

Step 1:
[image: step 1]

Step 2:
[image: step 2]

Answer (score 0):

Using the Windows Explorer context menu is the quickest option if you are working from Explorer and want to unzip the whole archive - the "Extract Files ..." option brings up a suitable UI.

If you already have 7zip open or use 7zip as your explorer, select the folders/files you want to extract and choose "Copy To ...", again you get a location chooser.

You can also use the favorites feature if you want to unpack to the same place each time but there is no option to always unpack to the same place.